# how to get the image name to display in a textview?

Tags: android, image, textview

I am creating an android app where in i have a browse button for the user to `browse an image from the image gallery`.
i am getting the selected image but i need the `name of the image to be displayed in a textview` in my activity how do i do that????
I am getting the image in this way:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
            img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);

            upload_row=new TableRow(this);

            appln_no=new TextView(this);
            image_name=new TextView(this);
            doctype=new TextView(this);

            appln_no.setText("Application no.");
            image_name.setText(selectedImagePath);
            doctype.setText("DOCUMENT_TYPE");

            upload_row.addView(appln_no);
            upload_row.addView(image_name);
            upload_row.addView(doctype);

            upload_table.addView(upload_row);

        }
    }
}
```

Can somebody please tell me how can I get the image name in a string to display it ????

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the real path use the below function

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
// can post image
String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
Cursor cursor = managedQuery( contentUri,
proj, // Which columns to return
null, // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
null, // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
null); // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
cursor.moveToFirst();
return cursor.getString(column_index); 

   }
```

Get the real path

```
     Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
     String s= getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
```

Use substring as below

```
     String name = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
     // instead of "/" you can also use File.sepearator
     System.out.println("......"+ name);
     image_name=new TextView(ActivityName.this);
     image_name.setText(name);
```

Example :

```
    String str="/storage/sdcard0/MyFolder/After school children sports day.jpg";
    System.out.println("......"+ str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
```

Output

```
    ......After school children sports day.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

try `data.getData().getLastPathSegment()` this should give you the image name